# base64 from mobile to php via ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, base64

I am trying, without any success, even with researching, to have a photo taken on a mobile device, which puts into a base64 long string, and send it to a php that then uploads it a database.

The issue i am having is, getting the full base64 code to the php file.  Here is my jquery code:

```
var imgData = localStorage.getItem('imgFile');
var propid = 213;
var tbl = 'tbl_images';
var sitch = 'images';

//console.log(imgData);

$.ajax({
   url: 'http://website.com/info/fn.php',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: JSON.stringify({'switch' : sitch, table : tbl, propid : propid, imgData : imgData}),
   type: 'POST',


    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);

    }
```

});

This is how the json looks:

```
data%3Aimage%2Fjpeg%3Bbase64%2CiVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPoAAAD6CAYAAACI7Fo9AAAAHGlET1QAAAACAAAAAAAAAH0AAAAoAAAAfQAAAH0AASpQSGstYwAAQABJREFUeAFsnXV7Xee17f0tbpnTpJQ0aCcOmCVZLFkWmpmZmSXbAoPMtmyZZBIzyxxmhiZpSmlTOs1pe9Jm3N94l3aa89z7x3zWXmuvvST58XjHmGPOd%2B4Bf5X0X18Kn%2F%2BF%2BDPxx%2F74m
```

So going to the PHP its looking like, and thus coming back, so even if it was the full length, the '%' will put it off from working.

So I would like some help on how to ensure the full code is going, and ensure its in the correct format.

Thanks in advance.

NOTE:  I did not put the PHP file here, as I did not think thats the problem, it is receiving the data, but just not all of it. Based on the console, its not seeing all of the base64.

**UPDATE**

By removing the json.stringify as per the first answer, the raw base64 was not formatted correctly, with the wrong chars in it.  If I leave it in.  It does format right, and i get the full raw image data.  But then my PHP file is not receiving it.  I see it in console, check it against a img decoder, works fine, but the $_POST is empty ?

**UPDATE 2**

I have changed it from `$_POST` to this:

```
if(!$_POST) {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    print_r($data);
    $switch = $data->switch;
} else {
    $switch = $_POST['switch'];
}
```

I can see using console.log, that the full image is sent in the POST via Ajax using the code above.  When i think put this into a query string, it does not take the whole binary, just a small part?

I cannot work out why it's not playing :(

Answer (score 1):

You're telling jquery to send JSON, but then manually encoding your object. That means the `data` parameter, in the ajax function, as written, will just be a plain string. Since you've told jquery to send json, it'll RE-encode that string.

You should have only

```
data: {'switch' : sitch, table : tbl, propid : propid, imgData : imgData}
```

jquery will do the grunt work of converting that object to json for you.

Comment: Okay, I think i am getting all the data, looks long enough, but i cannot check it, because its not formatted correctly.  Has lots '%' which is not right ?

Comment: if I var_dump($_POST) I get array[0] {}   Does this mean the POST is empty ?

Comment: yep. which means jquery isn't sending a post for some reason, or there's some kind of redirect occuring and your post is being shuffled around and turning into a get.

Comment: Yes, as its fine in console, checked and its the image in full., but the POST is empty, so the PHP file is not getting it?   Any ideas how i can see why this would happen, anything in the header I should look for ?  Thank you :)

Comment: use something like firebug or httpfox in firefox (or equiv tools in other browser) to watch the requests. you'll see if there's any redirects occuring.

Comment: I am using Chrome, so I guess it would be Network, I see the php file being called, and the request data, which is the raw base64 in the right format.   Method is POST in the request header also.

Comment: I used this in stead `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); $data->imgData`  but I am sure the whole string is not being received?  It is in console when I look at the request.  but if i `var_dump($data->imgData)` I am not getting whats in the request and short half the image ?